# Remove newlines from text usin constant PHP_EOL

Tags: php

```
$str = "1
2";
$str = preg_replace( "#".PHP_EOL."|\t#", "", $str );
$hand = fopen("t.txt", "w+");
fwrite($hand, $str);
fclose($hand);
```

I need that remove newlines and horizontal tabs from string and then write into `txt` file.

The code above, removes only horizontal tabs, but newlines  stays, that is in text file is writed:

```
1
2
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: `preg_replace( "#". PHP_EOL ."|\t#", "", $str )`; if you want to use that constant. Your code looks for string constant "PHP_EOL". Also, why preg_replace when you can do simple str_replace here?

Comment: @ N.B. Ups, I really use this: `"#". PHP_EOL ."|\t#"` . I will update my  question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/([\r\n\t])/','', $str);
```

No need to use `PHP_EOL` as it's just translated in to a `\n` anyways. Just some OSs (like windows) use `\r\n` (which is why the constant exists) but that doesn't change the meaning of `\r` or `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

`PHP_EOL` is [OS dependent](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php). So `\r\n` on Windows and `\n` on Linux.

If you have a file that has `\r\n` and you remove newlines on a Linux system using `PHP_EOL` you're going to get similar results: the `\r` will still be in the file.

Change the regex to simply include all forms: `"#\r|\n|\t#"`